# How to open multiple window in electron using electron-window-manager

Tags: node.js, electron

I am implementing an note app in electron. So i want to open multiple window to show the notes but i am not able to do it. I am using the below code in main process.

```
function createWindow () {
    let sql = "Select count(*) as totalNotes from notes";
    var total = db.get(sql, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message)
        }
        for(var i=0; i< row.totalNotes; i++) {
            var win = windowManager.open('home', 'Window2_'+(i+1), __dirname+'/index.html?version='+(i+1), false, {
                'onLoadFailure': function(window){
                     console.log(window);
                 },
                 minWidth: 570, minHeight: 470, width: 570, height: 470, frame: true, resizable: false
            })
        }
    })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Comment: How does it fail? What error message do you get? Are you certain that SQLite is part of the problem? Does the program work without involving SQLite?

Comment: @Corion sqlite is not an issue . Its not working without using sqlite.

Comment: Why do you add the `sqlite` and `sqlite3` tags then, if the problem has nothing to do with SQLite? Please clean up the tags.

Comment: Ok @Corion 
Do you have any idea about it?